# Code in VSCODE all turn white and taking forever to run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Out of nowhere, every line of code will all turn white and even the simplest import numpy command will take forever to run.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue.
Thanks!

Everything will be working fine every time I reopen vscode but the same issue will return after a couple of minutes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9f9i.png)

Comment: Have you check your jupyter kernel and python interpreter?

Comment: does this just happen for you in Jupyter notebooks? Or also in Python files? What version of the Pylance extension do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are running the code through a jupyter notebook. Please try running the code straight through python on your device .

Comment: `running the code virtually` what does that mean? He uses a Jupyter notebook and that is just a redirection of input and output to a normal Python interpreter